# Security using AES with salted password as key

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, aes, storage

I understand how a salted hash of a password works, but I am assuming I would also need to store the salt, username, KEY, and encryptedpassword. I think overall I just need to understand how I would implement this for instance how to store it and then how to regenerate the password. Also if someone could explain why using this salted value is better, couldn't a person do a dictionary attack with the salt in front of each word?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to regenerate the password? It is a better idea to use one-way encryption for passwords.

Comment: The only reason of hashing with salt is to NOT allow to regenerate password.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to do: verify a supplied password is correct (as with a system login); or implement encryption of data where the key is derived from a password.

If it is the latter (which is known as *password-based encryption*), then you should use a *key derivation function*, such as `PBKDF2`.  A key derivation function takes a salt and a supplied user password, and produces a key that can be used with a cipher like AES.

To encrypt, you would prompt for a password, generate a random salt, and derive a key using the KDF.  You would then use that key with AES in a suitable block cipher mode to encrypt the data, and store *only* the salt and the encrypted data (and whatever IV the cipher mode requires).

To decrypt, you would prompt for a password, load the salt from the file, and re-derive the key.  You would then use that key to decrypt the file.

The purpose of the salt is to prevent precomputation optimisations from being applied to a dictionary attack.  It is indeed possible to perform a bruteforce dictionary attack once the salt is known, but the KDF is designed to be slow enough to make this infeasible without precomputation.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a hash algorithm to store your passwords, which is a one way "encryption". Then you can just hash the password you get from the user and compare to the stored hash.

You should for security reasons, add a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to your hash, so as to make rainbow table attack's on your hashes harder.

You will need to store the salt so you can get the same hash, when computing a hash on the user's input.  You should store the salt in a secure way.