# My SQL Server CLR function is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, performance, clr

I have created two methods in C#:

```
public static string Encrypt(string clearText, string encryptionKey)
{
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }

                clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }

        return clearText;
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string encryptionKey)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }

                    cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return cipherText;
    }
```

By following the steps given in [This Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37377/SQL-Server-CLR-Functions), I have created a CLR function in SQL Server and I am trying to call it like:

```
SELECT dbo.Decrypt(MyEncrypted, EncryptionKey)
FROM   MyTable
```

The problem is, it is taking **TOO MUCH TIME**. Like for only 1000 rows, it took 1.5 minutes. If I call my query without the CLR function, it took less than 1 second.

Is there any thing I can do to improve the performance of the CLR functions?

Comment: can you use sql server's encryption? why are you saving it as a string when you could save the raw bytes?

Comment: Will it improve the performance?

Comment: perhaps. you will have to test it.

Comment: What is the size of data in the "MyEncrypted" and "EncryptionKey" columns? How long does that code take when running in a C# console app with the exact same inputs?

Comment: Size of "MyEncrypted" is NVARCHAR(1000) and EncryptionKey is NVARCHAR(256)...

Comment: 0.09 seconds a row is slow?  Commands have to be sent between database and c# application which takes time.  There could be a firewall or virus checker that is validating contents which could add time.  You may not be able to get better performance.  You may be able to improve performance by make so objects static and calling the constructor only once rather than every time the method is called.

Comment: @jdweng the OP is using this code as a CLR function, so it runs on the sqlserver, in the same process but in a separate app-domain, no firewalls are involved...

Comment: rene : Not necessarily true.  Is the transfer of data a virtual connection?

Comment: @jdweng I tried with static class, Still no improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've analyzed your `Decrypt` method with the Performance Analyzer in VS2010 by running it 100 times:

[image: hottest path is GetBytes]

As you can see the [`GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(v=vs.110).aspx) instance take the most time.

I'm not sure why you have these specific encryption/decryption requirements but one way influence the time the `GetBytes` method takes is to instantiate the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` using the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx129kfs(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes iterations as the third parameter. Default it is on 1000, I  can set it as low as 1. **BUT THIS IS STRONGLY ADVISED AGAINST**

```
var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encryptionKey, salt, 10);
```

This iterations does need to be the same for both the `Encrypt` and `Decrypt` so you'll have to Decrypt\Encrypt your current values if you want to change that.

One other option might be to cache the IV values as seems to recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18379507/578411). I'm not enough of an expert if they talk there about using the same Key as well but if that is an option you might cache the call to `GetBytes` for the key as well.

All the described change have impact on how your data is encrypted and the strength of your encryption. Consider both impacts when testing the solutions.

Comment: Reducing the number of iteration on key derivation functions has cryptographic consequences. Don't recommend it for perf gain.

Comment: OK noted. and the caching part, store the IV in the table and read the KEY from  a config file/ registry @RemusRusanu so you won't need the GetBytes calls on decrypt?

Comment: ... or use SQL Server built-in [`ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx)

Comment: @rene Thanks for your effort but changing the algorithm is not an option for us.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Also database encryption is not an option. :(

Comment: @rene Your statistics helped me a lot. Now I have changed my algorithm according to new algorithm and it is working fine. Here is the solution given in another link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168240/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-in-c-sharp